# While loop doesn't start

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

All code previously working properly.
It seems that when I get to the while loop does not execute the contents inside, place the code so you can evaluate:

```
String linea = "";
BufferedReader lettore = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("log.txt"));
int lineCount = 0;
int posizione = 0;

while((linea = lettore.readLine()) != null)  
{
     lineCount++;
     posizione = linea.indexOf(client);
}
```

Comment: WIth a name like that, you should be able to use your debugger.

Comment: do you get any error/exception? Is file log.txt present? if yes does it have any lines in it? Does it has read permissions on it?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: In fact there seems to be no mistake.

Comment: No exception, anyway. I Before run the code I posted check if the file exists, if it does not exist create it, and in fact everything is successful.

Comment: Is there content in your file?

Comment: put your readLine()  before while loop and print its content

Comment: No the file is empty. But should still enter in the loop.

Comment: If it is empty, no it will not. It will instantly return null.

Comment: WHY?!!! which line will it read from an empty file ?

Comment: @Debug Why do you believe it would read something if the file is empty? Please read the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) and rethink your program.

Comment: Ah, so I think I have the wrong condition. I understand that should read the file until it has finished its contents.

Comment: `I understand that should read the file until it has finished its contents` and that is what it does. If the file is empty, then this condition will be instantly true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. It looks like either 'log.txt' file is empty or you are making a false assumption of non executed code.

Comment: this doesnt provide answer to question, if you want the asker to try something out, please comment do not answer

Comment: The file is in fact empty, but is still not activated the necessary condition of the while loop.

Comment: If the file is empty lettore.readLine() will be null and your code block in while loop will not be run.

Answer (score 0):

If the file exists and is non-empty then the code will work (assuming "client" exists and is non-null).

if the file does not exist you will get an exception.

if the file exists but is empty, the loop will not be entered.